# how to set limts on x and y axis Openpyxl charts

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

I am working on script to plot data in excel sheets using openpyxl module i am able to plot the data , could not find a way to set limit on axis while plotting

here is my code

```
ws2 = ws2 = wb.create_sheet()
xvalues = Reference(ws2, (2, 1), (10, 1))
yvalues = Reference(ws2, (2,2), (10,2))
xseries = Series(xvalues, title="First series of values")
yseries = Series(yvalues, title="Second series of values",xvalues = xseries)
chart = ScatterChart()
chart.append(yseries)
ws2.add_chart(chart)
ws2.save("C5122_534_09112014.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on spacing for major gridlines. I found the solution in the codes openpyxl > chart > axis.py in the lib.

```
chart_2.y_axis.scaling.min = 10 # minimum limit of axis
chart_2.y_axis.scaling.max = 90 # maximum limit if axis
chart_2.y_axis.majorUnit = 20   # spacing of gridlines
```

Hope it will also work for you. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Initially the chart module was setup to calculate axes maxima and minima for you. You can override this by setting `auto_axis=False` when you create the chart. You can then set the maximum and minimum for an axis:

```
chart = ScatterChart(auto_axis=False)
chart.x_axis.min = 5
chart.x_axis.max = 10
chart.x_axis.unit = 1
```

In 2.2 the default will not be to try and be so clever.

Comment: File "DVT_Result_extraction_general.py", line 374, in key_worksheet
    chart = ScatterChart(auto_axis=False)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auto_axis'

Comment: Hello Charlie i am getting an error when defining ScatterChart, Thanks for the help

Comment: You're right, looks like the code needs correcting. But you can also simply set the value after initialising the class. `chart.auto_axis = False`

Comment: I used it similar way, worked perfectly for me, thanks

Comment: Glad, it's working. FWIW 2.1.1 should allow you to pass in `auto_axis=False` into the constructor.

By the way xlsxwriter has more complete support for writing charts.